# Python list sum elements

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this list in Python:

```
[['jhidalgo', 19, u'6,8'],
['jhidalgo', 19, u'5,3'],
['jhidalgo', 20, u'7'],
['jhidalgo', 20, u'0,4'],
['jhidalgo', 20, u'0'],
['jhidalgo', 20, u'1,6'],
['jhidalgo', 21, u'6,9'],
['jhidalgo', 22, u'1,3'],
['jhidalgo', 23, u'6,9'],
['jtern', 19, u'6,9'],
['jtern', 19, u'3,2']
]
```

I need to sum numbers after `u` letter in case if two previous elements are the same:

```
  ['jhidalgo', 19, u'6,8'],
  ['jhidalgo', 19, u'5,3'],
```

These two strings have two identical elements: jhidalgo and 19. So we could sum numbers after the `u` letter: *6,8 + 5,3 = 12,1*

How can I get a list like this?

```
[['jhidalgo', 19, u'12,1'],
['jhidalgo', 20, u'9'],
['jhidalgo', 21, u'6,9'],
['jhidalgo', 22, u'1,3'],
['jhidalgo', 23, u'6,9'],
['jtern', 19, u'10,1']
]
```

I need to sum the `third` element by grouping the `second` and `first` element. 
For example, all the `jhidalgo` with `20`...the sum is `7+0.4+0+1.6 = 9`

Comment: Should the 3rd element be interpreted as a rational number? `6.8 + 5.3` would sum to `12.1`, by that interpretation. Did you try anything yourself yet? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Also, is your input sorted on the first and second column?

Comment: If you posted your attempt as martijin says we could help you :).

Comment: sorry, I have no idea about how to sort it out. I would appreciate any help

Comment: I don't understand what or how are you summing, e.g. how did you get the second result of `['jhidalgo', 20, u'9']`?

Comment: I need to sum the third element grouping by the second, for every first element. For example, all the jhidalgo with a 20...the sum is 7+0.4+0+1.6 = 9

Comment: @Madmartigan so the expected output would contain a float and not a string wiht `,`

Comment: yes, thats' correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the values are intended to interpret commas as decimal points, and that all values to be grouped are consecutive, you can use `itertools.groupby` to good effect here:

```
import itertools
from math import fsum
from operator import itemgetter

mylist = [...]

summed = [(name, num, fsum(float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in g))
          for (name, num), g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=itemgetter(0, 1))]
```

Using `groupby` is the best solution if the data is already consecutive by key (and preserves order without difficulty), but if the values to be grouped are not consecutive, you can either sort (by the same key used for `groupby`), e.g. running `mylist.sort(key=itemgetter(0, 1))` before computing `summed` with `groupby` as above, or to avoid `O(n log n)` sort costs, you can use a `dict` (or for simplicity, `defaultdict(float)`) to group non-consecutive groups:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sumdict = defaultdict(float)
for name, num, val in mylist:
    sumdict[name, num] += float(val.replace(',', '.'))

# Side-note: I'd have used tuple/namedtuple for the triples here since the data likely
# shouldn't be mutable, and tuples are the "proper" type for fixed length,
# heterogeneous, immutable data, but the functional difference is minimal
summed = [[name, num, valsum] for (name, num), valsum in sorted(sumdict.items())]
```

Comment: My program cannot import name fsum. I dont know why

Comment: @Madmartigan: Well, it's not necessary (though it should exist in any Python 2.6 or higher). You can just use plain `sum` if `fsum` isn't available, [`fsum` is just a higher accuracy `sum` specifically for `float`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum).

Comment: @Madmartigan: Side-note: Most likely cause of `fsum` not being available is that you named a package `math` or a module `math.py` (or a subpackage/submodule if you're on Python 2.x, didn't do `from __future__ import absolute_import`, and the module importing from `math` is a sibling to the `math` subpackage/submodule).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I wish you all a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas, It's a great python module for data analysis.

Or:

```
# sorting
d = {}
for name, value, amount in l:
    if (name, value) not in d:
        d[name, value] = 0
    d[name, value] += float(amount.replace(',', '.'))

# rewriting list
result = []
for (k, v), a in d.items():
    result.append([k, v, str(a).replace('.', ',')])
```

Comment: thanks!, It works fantastically. Now I have to study the code

Comment: OOC, any reason you chose to use nested `dict`s? `dict`s can be keyed by a `tuple` (`d[name, value]` is perfectly legal), and since we're not using the name grouping separately from the `name, value` grouping, it seems pointless to nest.

Comment: You're right. Didn't came to my mind.. I edit